# ¿Como controlar el evento Leave o Validated de un textbox dentro de un MDI container?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

El detalle es que tengo un `form` el cual llamo `frmPrincipal` el cual tiene la propiedad `MDiContainer` como verdadera, al iniciar el form mando llamar como `child` un formulario llamado `frmArticulo`. La idea principal es que si al momento de registrar un nuevo artículo y la clave de la unidad de medida no existe en la base de datos, pueda abrir en automático el formulario de captura de nueva unidad de medida.

3 forms (`frmPrincipal`, `frmArticulo`, `frmUnidadMedida`)

```
//Evento load del formulario principal
private void frmPrincipal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Articulos frm1 = new Articulos();
    frm1.MdiParent = this;
    frm1.Show();
}

//Envento Leave del textbox unidad de medida en form articulo
private void txtUnidadMedida_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //El metodo BuscarUnidadMedida consulta la DB y devuelve true
    //si se encuetra registrado, si no abre el form unidad medida
    //para registrar dicho valor
    if (!Consulta.BuscarUnidadMedida(txtUnidadMedida.Text))
    {
        frmUnidadMedida frm2 = new frmUnidadMedida();
        frm2.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
        frm2.Show();
    }    
}
```

Con lo que me encuentro es que al momento de que el `txtUnidadMedida` pierde el foco busca en la base de datos y si no encuentra el valor, abre el formulario para capturar la nueva unidad de medida, pero este evento se ejecuta dos veces, por lo que el resultado en pantalla es que se muestran dos veces el `frmUnidadMedida`.

No logro encontrar porque al abrir por primera vez el form `frmUnidadMedida` se vuelve a ejecutar el evento de `txtUnidadMedida_Leave`.

Si alguien se ha encontrado en un caso similar podría orientarme al respecto.

Comment: ¿Has intentado luego del `frm2.Show();` hacer un `.Focus();` o `Select();` en dicho formulario nuevo? (frmUnidadMedida)? ¿También has intentado utilizar en vez del evento `Leave()` del `Textbox`, el evento `LostFocus`? Finalmente puedes intentar saltar en el código del debugger con F11 para visualizar en que momento se repite el evento.

Comment: @AgustinM. El evento **LostFocus** era lo que estaba buscando. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Entonces fabricamos una respuesta para que la pregunta no quede en vano.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías intentar utilizar el evento **`LostFocus`** en vez de `Leave`.

Tu problema puede suceder ya que el evento Leave lo ejecutan varias acciones y por eso se abren dos veces el formulario, siendo deseado una vez sola.